# How to "emitter.setMaxListeners()"?

Tags: node.js, httprequest

When I do a GET on a certain URI using the node.js 'request' module;

```
var options = {uri:"aURI", headers:headerData};
request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
}
```

**The error message is:**

```
[Error: Exceeded maxRedirects. Probably stuck in a redirect loop.]
```

**and there is also the following message:**

```
"(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit."
```

How do I `setMaxListeners`?

Answer (score 120, accepted):

I strongly advice NOT to use the code:

```
process.setMaxListeners(0);
```

The warning is not there without reason. Most of the time, it is because there is an error hidden in your code. Removing the limit removes the warning, but not its cause, and prevents you from being warned of a source of resource leakage.

If you hit the limit for a legitimate reason, put a reasonable value in the function (the default is 10).

Also, to change the default, it is not necessary to mess with the EventEmitter prototype. you can set the value of defaultMaxListeners attribute like so:

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 15;
```

Comment: How to identify the cause of the resource leakage?

Comment: in short : debugging. Their is many things that can cause resource leakage. and there is some tools that can help detect them. but their is not magic way to find any bug.

Comment: You might use `require('events').defaultMaxListeners = 15;` directly.

Comment: where to use it in react native

Comment: I even more strongly advise to use it :D

Comment: Where should I use this code, I have the same problem, I need to edit a file or what?

Answer (score 34):

I use the code to increase the default limit globally:

`require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;`

Comment: Had this problem in jenkins running a casperjs script, added this line at top of script and it works!.  Thanks  
var y = require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;

Comment: this don't work for me. 
The bellow is working: 
require('events').defaultMaxListeners = 15;

Answer (score 7):

Although adding something to nodejs module is possible, it seems to be not the best way (if you try to run your code on other computer, the program will crash with the same error, obviously).

I would rather set max listeners number in your own code:

```
var options = {uri:headingUri, headers:headerData, maxRedirects:100};
request.setMaxListeners(0);
request.get(options, function (error, response, body) {
}
```

Comment: This gives `request.setMaxListeners is not a function` error. You have to chain it on `request.get(…, function(){…}).setMaxListeners(0)` ([related ques](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093457/has-no-method-setmaxlisteners-error))

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = Infinity;
```

Answer (score -3):

this is Extension to @Félix Brunet  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44143119/1390678)

**Reason** - there is code **hidden** in your app

**How to find -**

- Strip/comment code and execute until you reach error
- check log file

**Eg** - In my case i created 30 instances of [winston log](https://github.com/winstonjs/winston) **Unknowingly** and it started giving error

**Note :** if u supress this error , it will come again afetr 3..4 days

Answer (score -4):

It also happened to me

I use this code and it worked

```
require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = infinity;
```

Try it out. It may help

Thanks

Comment: Update the [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60170831/735926) instead of copy/pasting it.