# Custom NodeJS Webcrawler

Tags: node.js, web-crawler

I'm trying to build a basic webcrawler using Node.  I've tried as many of the crawler modules that I could find, and none of them are working well for me, so I thought I'd try to roll my own.  Basically, I'm using the "request" module, and recursively calling the "get" function [of request] for every link that I find on a page.

It seems to be working well, and after 100 pages, the memory usage is still low, but after about 14 pages, I'm getting a Node warning about maximum event emitters and a possible memory leak.

Is this a safe way to go about writing a webcrawler?  Is there anything I need to take into account?  Is there a better way to go about it?

Thanks!

UPDATE: Code below:

```
var request = require('request');
var $       = require('jquery');
var _       = require("underscore");
var S       = require('string');
var jsdom   = require('jsdom');

var startURL    = 'http://www.cnn.com/sitemap/';
var host        = 'http://www.cnn.com';
var blocked     = [];
var totalDepth  = 1;

var urls        = [];
var ignored     = [];
var results     = [];
var counter     = 0;

processURL(startURL,totalDepth);

function processURL(url,depth) {

    request(url, function (error, response, html) {

      if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {

        var title = html.match("<title>(.*?)</title>");
            title=title ? title[1] : '';


        var myURL=url;
        myURL = myURL.split(',').join(' ');
        title = title.split(',').join(' ');
        displayURL = myURL.replace(host,'');
        results.push(myURL + ',' + title);
        counter++;

        if(results.length==100) {
            saveResults();
        }


        if(depth>0) {
            jsdom.env({
                html: html,
                scripts: ['http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.min.js']
                }, function (err, window) {
                var $ = window.jQuery;
                if($!=undefined) {
                $('a').each(function() {
                    var href=$(this).attr('href');
                    href=fixURL(href);
                    if(checkURL(href)) {
                        addToQueue(href,depth-1);                       
                    } 
                })
              }
            });
        }
    }   
});
}

var int=setInterval(function(){checkExit()},10000);

function checkExit() {

    if(results.length==0) {
        process.exit();
    }

    saveResults();

}

function checkURL(url) {

    if(url==undefined) return false;
    if(url=='')  return false;
    if(url=='#') return false;
    if(url=='')  return false;
    if(url=='/') return false;
    if(S(url).startsWith('#')) return false;
    if(url.indexOf('javascript')==0) return false;

    if(url.indexOf("/")==0) {
        url=host+url;
    }

    if(_.contains(urls,url)) {        
        return false;
    }

    if(_.contains(ignored,url)) {        
        return false;
    }    

    $.each(blocked,function(i,d) {
        if(S(url).contains(d)) {
            ignored.push(url);
            return false;
        }
    })

    if(url.indexOf('http')==0) {
        if(S(url).startsWith(host)) {
            return true;
    }   else
            return false;
    }

    return true;                  
}

function addToQueue(url,depth) {

    if(_.contains(urls,url)) {        
        return false;
    }

    if(url.indexOf("/")==0) {
        url=host+url;
    }

    if(!validURL(url)) {
        return;
    }

    processURL(url,depth);
    urls.push(url); 

}

function saveResults() {
    var csv = '';
    $.each(results,function(i,d) {
        csv+=d + '\n';
    })
    writeData(csv);
    results = [];
}

function writeData(data) {
    var fs = require('fs');    
    fs.appendFile(__dirname+'/results.csv', data, function(err) {
        if(err) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            console.log("******The file was saved!******");            
        }
    }); 
}

function validURL(value) {
    var urlregex = new RegExp("^(http:\/\/www.|https:\/\/www.|ftp:\/\/www.|www.){1}([0-9A-Za-z]+\.)");
    if (urlregex.test(value)) {
        return (true);
    }
    return (false);
}

function fixURL(url) {
    if(url==undefined) return '';
    if(url.indexOf("/")==0) {
        return host+url;
    } else {
        return url;
    }
}
```

Comment: Post your current code.

Comment: I think the more general question about memory leaks is interesting. You might want to focus your question there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13983204/nodejs-warning-possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected-11-listeners-added

Answer (score 2):

You are hitting node's very conservative/low threshold of [max event listeners](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n) for a given event emitter. Most likely, you have a bug in your code where you are adding listeners over and over to the same emitter where you could be reusing them. You need to post your code in order for us to analyze it, but either you have a legitimate need to increase this value or you are mistakenly adding redundant listeners to the same emitter.

You may also want to understand the [maxSockets](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_agent_maxsockets) parameter, but probably not adjust it as that could move your code from well-behaved crawler into nuisance denial of service bot.