# Nodejs memory leaks on cancelling download with download manager

Tags: node.js, memory-leaks, express, download, listener

I created a simple file downloader using Expressjs 3 and Nodejs 0.10

```
function download(req, res, filepath, filename){
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/force-download');
    res.header('Content-Type', 'application/octet-stream');
    res.attachment(filename);
    res.download(filepath, filename);
}
```

Everything is OK, but when I test application with download managers (for example Internet Download Manager), when I abort or cancel download (before or during download), it throws a warning:

```
Trace
    at Socket.EventEmitter.addListener (events.js:160:15)
    at Socket.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:653:33)
    at Socket.EventEmitter.once (events.js:179:8)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:512:26)

(node) warning: <b>possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 listeners added. Use
emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.</b>
```

How can I remove listener after aborting file download?

Comment: Answered [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9768586/893780).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved
Add **setMaxListeners(0)** after Expressjs definition:

```
var express = require('express');

//expressjs 2.x
//var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

//expressjs 3.x
var app = module.exports = express();

//ADD BELOW CODE
app.setMaxListeners(0);
```

Thanks to @robertklep

Comment: This simply removes the limit of listeners that can attach to an `EventEmitter`. The question was about removing event listeners.

Comment: Yeah, you still have the event listeners there, all you did was suppress the warning messages.