# nodejs connect mongo have memory leak

Tags: node.js, mongodb

In node.js I use expressjs and when connect to mongodb, I have a trouble and I have no idea why it happens. I search about it but it's unclear.

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 reconnect listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:179:15)
    at Server.connect (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:291:17)
    at open (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:206:19)
    at Db.open (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/db.js:229:44)
    at Function.User.get (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/models/user.js:55:10)
    at Context.<anonymous> (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/test/models/userSpec.js:63:9)
    at Test.Runnable.run (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runnable.js:233:15)
    at Runner.runTest (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:390:10)
    at /home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:473:12
    at next (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:315:14)
    at /home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:325:7
    at next (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:260:23)
    at Immediate._onImmediate (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mocha/lib/runner.js:292:5)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:367:17)
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 destroy listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
Trace
    at addListener (events.js:179:15)
    at once (events.js:204:8)
    at connectHandler (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/lib/server.js:265:19)
    at g (events.js:199:16)
    at emit (events.js:107:17)
    at /home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:399:23
    at /home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:806:13
    at Callbacks.emit (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:95:3)
    at null.messageHandler (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/topologies/server.js:246:23)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (/home/repository/nodejs/blog/N-blog/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/lib/connection/connection.js:262:22)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:107:17)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:163:16)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:126:10)
    at TCP.onread (net.js:538:20)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [possible EventEmitter memory leak detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected)