# Node.js server is constantly returning MaxListenersExceededWarning

Tags: node.js, nodejs-server

My production server is returning the following error:

```
MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 81 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
1|pro_app  | 2019-03-19 15:59:01: MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 81 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
1|pro_app  |     at _addListener (events.js:243:17)
1|pro_app  |     at Connection.addListener (events.js:259:10)
1|pro_app  |     at Connection.Readable.on (_stream_readable.js:796:35)
1|pro_app  |     at Connection.once (events.js:290:8)
1|pro_app  |     at Connection._send (/var/www/app/node_modules/http2/lib/protocol/connection.js:355:10)
1|pro_app  |     at runCallback (timers.js:696:18)
1|pro_app  |     at tryOnImmediate (timers.js:667:5)
1|pro_app  |     at processImmediate (timers.js:649:5)
1|pro_app  |     at process.topLevelDomainCallback (domain.js:121:23)
```

Although I have been trying to deal with this error by increasing the listeners number as mentioned in the following links:

[Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected)

[node.js official website](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)

I still keep getting the same error, regardless the amount of listeners.
The only way of stopping this error, is setting `process.setMaxListeners(0)` but I'm afraid doing it will prevent me from detecting memory leaks.

Would you suggest to just set `process.setMaxListeners(0)` ? Or first make sure there are no memory leaks? I've been searching for memory leaks detection tool, but with no unambiguous result. if you any suggestion for this kind of tool, it would be definitely be helpful!

Comment: Does the number of listeners reported keep increasing?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Warning: Possible EventEmitter - Node warning when running \`foundation new\`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39254438/warning-possible-eventemitter-node-warning-when-running-foundation-new)

Comment: Yes, the number of listeners keep increasing, I constantly see this error @Ferrybig

Comment: If the number keeps increasing, you have a memory leak at the moment. The proper way to solve it is to solve the memory leak, and turning the check off is not recommended. Not fixing it will cause random crashes in your production server in the future if it isn't restarted often enough

Comment: @Ferrybig is there any tool for finding leak memory you suggest?