# react-native ios project + memory leak

Tags: ios, memory, mobile, react-native

I am using react-native for iOS. My project has the following warning:

> Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 error listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit<.

I do not use `DeviceEventEmitter`, and I use Keyboard component.

Comment: See if this helps https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/13806

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Flux by any chance if not please provide the npm link to the component you are using.

Comment: Yes, I am using Flux:  var Dispatcher = require("flux").Dispatcher;

module.exports = new Dispatcher(); And after that I use this Dispatcher: Dispatcher.dispatch(...) Is there any problem with Flux?

Comment: one of your stores is exceeding  10 listeners Limit 
var AppDispatcher = require('../Dispatcher/Dispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
/* By Default, a maximum of 10 listeners can be registered for any single event. more here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected/26176922#26176922 */

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info

Answer (score 0):

One of your Stores is Exceeding what EventEmitter is capable of. Just Do this.

```
var AppDispatcher = require('../Dispatcher/Dispatcher');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 100;
```

/* By Default, a maximum of 10 listeners can be registered for any single event. more here:
[possible EventEmitter memory leak detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected/26176922#26176922) */

Comment: Thanks a lot for the info

Comment: uhh.... it doesn't look like the first two lines do anything... am I missing something.