# How to terminate an single gulp.watch change event listener while keeping the gulp script running

Tags: npm, gulp

How to terminate an gulp.watch change event listener without terminating the rest of the gulp script?

Not an very elegant test case:

```
function paths() {
    var paths = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('../../z/paths.json'))
    gulp.watch(paths.scriptsFiles, ['test'])

    return paths
}
gulp.task('test', () =>
    gulp.src(paths().scriptsFiles)
        .pipe(...)
        .pipe(...)
)
```

Which leads to this error:

*MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 change listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit*

Comment: can you show what you tried?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26176922/7045253 might helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I stumbled upon [chokidar](https://github.com/paulmillr/chokidar) which says to be the underlying package in gulp. It is also very well documented with code examples.