# Error: Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, postgresql

While running test I got warning using Postgresql.

> Warning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11
>   uncaughtException listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [possible EventEmitter memory leak detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected)

Comment: It is googled immediately if you use the exact error message. Please do so before you ask a question next time.

Comment: @zerkms thanks for your reply and sorry for so late response.that error was actually fixed by closing Postgres DB connection in each test.
Off course I googled before posting here might be I need to put some more detail of the problem I was facing.