# Error - EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup

Tags: node.js, eventemitter

Error:

```
(node) warning: possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 wakeup listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.
```

The question is whether to pay attention to it and increase the limits? Or can I ignore it? In fact, it does not affect

```
NodeJS 0.12.18
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [possible EventEmitter memory leak detected](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected)

Comment: @Veve you wrong!

Comment: @Veve my question is another!

Comment: I want to know, how it can affect on my app,  I do not wont to resolve this

Answer (score 0):

If you're expecting that `EventEmitter` to have more than ten listeners, then you should use `setMaxListeners()` to increase the limit.

If you were not expecting so many, then you probably have a listener leak (i.e. you keep adding instead of replacing).

Comment: Yes, If I do not pay attention to this error, will it be fatal?

Comment: Does it say "fatal" or "error"? No, it says "warning".