# How to use EventEmitter on net.createServer()

Tags: node.js

I got error:

> (node:1763) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 data listeners added. Use `emitter.setMaxListeners()` to increase limit.

How to solve this issue? This is my code example:

```
    var net = require('net');
    var server = net.createServer(function (socket) {
    socket.on('data', function (data) {
        /**
        * my logic
        */
    });

    socket.on('error', function(err) {

        console.log("Socket error");
        console.log(err)
    });

    socket.on('close', function() {

        console.log('Connection closed');
    });
});

server.listen(8888);
```

Comment: check out this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected

Comment: By default, a maximum of 10 listeners can be registered for any single event. To turn off this limit
```require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 0
```

Comment: other thing you should move the line ```server.listen(8888);
``` outside of createServer scope.