# create-react-app appname giving following warning

Tags: reactjs

```
Creating a new React app in C:\Users\riteshd\Documents\sap.

Installing packages. This might take a couple of minutes.
Installing react, react-dom, and react-scripts...

(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
(node:38104) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 drain listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Nodejs MaxListenersExceededWarning](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49946001/nodejs-maxlistenersexceededwarning)

Comment: are you using it like this npx create-react-app <appname>