# Memory Leaks in node.js: looking for minimal viable example of a memory leak with EventEmmiters

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, memory-leaks

I need to proof the concepts that it's possible to create a memory leak with EventEmmiters in node.js. I tried to google, but all of the examples are about frontend stuff(e.g.: Backbone views) or about polluting the global scope.

Comment: Hi, I've found a thread here in SO which might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected

Answer (score 0):

Create an eventListener each time some client is accessing a resource  for example. After 10 eventListener you'll have some node warnings.With 50-100 event listeners it should be bad enough. Then start to emit events it will probably not go well.

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/35e95981585fd2a494476a1e04a9d86b – can you check the example? it doesn't provide any, BTW

Comment: I would put the emitter instanciation outside the route function

Comment: https://gist.github.com/kharandziuk/ac2d05b945fc8061430203766c381480 – but still, memory usage doesn't grow