# MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, solidity

I am attempting to develop some tests for my Solidity contract. I have a `compile.js` script here:

```
const path = require('path');
const solc = require('solc');
const fs = require('fs-extra');

const buildPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'build');
fs.removeSync(buildPath);

const campaignPath = path.resolve(__dirname, 'contracts', 'Campaign.sol');
const source = fs.readFileSync(campaignPath, 'utf-8');
const output = solc.compile(source, 1).contracts;

fs.ensureDirSync(buildPath);

for (let contract in output) {
  fs.outputJsonSync(
    path.resolve(buildPath, contract.replace(':', '') + '.json'),
    output[contract]
  );
}
```

Could the culprit to this EventEmitter memory leakage be somewhere in this code? I have never ran into this error before. I get the error when I run my first test and this is my test file:

```
const assert = require('assert');
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const Web3 = require('web3');
const web3 = new Web3(ganache.provider());

const compiledFactory = require('../ethereum/build/CampaignFactory.json');
const compiledCampaign = require('../ethereum/build/Campaign.json');

let accounts;
let factory;
let campaignAddress;
let campaign;

beforeEach(async () => {
  accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();

  factory = await new web3.eth.Contract(JSON.parse(compiledFactory.interface))
    .deploy({ data: compiledFactory.bytecode })
    .send({ from: accounts[0], gas: '1000000' });

  await factory.methods.createCampaign('100').send({
    from: accounts[0],
    gas: '1000000'
  });

  [campaignAddress] = await factory.methods.getDeployedCampaigns().call();
  campaign = new web3.eth.Contract(
    JSON.parse(compiledCampaign.interface),
    campaignAddress
  );
});

describe('Campaigns', () => {
  it('deploys a factory and a campaign', () => {
    assert.ok(factory.options.address);
    assert.ok(campaign.options.address);
  });
});
```

The second error I get right after this EventEmitter memory leak is saying that my `getDeployedCampaigns()` is not a function, but it clearly is if you look at the `Campaign.sol` file here:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract CampaignFactory {
    address[] public deployedCampaigns;

    function createCampaign(uint minimum) public {
      address newCampaign = new Campaign(minimum, msg.sender);

      deployedCampaigns.push(newCampaign);
    }

    function getDeployedCampaigns() public view returns (address[]) {
        return deployedCampaigns;
    }
}
```

Comment: No idea what this Solidity thing compiles into, but apparently `getDeployedCampaigns` would be the function, whereas `getDeployedCampaigns()` (called, with parentheses) would be an array, right? (Or at least a promise-like object, on which `Function.call()` might have weird effects?)

Comment: Try looking into this question for the memory leak error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected. After this one is fixed we can look at web3 error.

Comment: @StockOverflaw The `getDeployedCampaigns().call()` is the correct way to call a solidty function from web3 as described on the web3 documentation page: https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth-contract.html#methods-mymethod-call. But the `.call()` part should have parameter but I don't think this has to do with the not a function error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is caused by a memory leak in the: web3.eth.Contract()

It has a known memory leak. I am currently dealing with a similar issue.

https://github.com/ChainSafe/web3.js/issues/3042