# Requests for multiple pages with puppeteer

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am trying to get information from many sites (links from array) which have dynamically content (emails and names of companies) with puppeteer. I use "for" cycle to iterate array with links, do `page.goto...` to each site, wait until the site is loaded , wait several seconds for dynamical content, and begin doing requests. But i have first and last request completed (Promises resolve). Other promises don't return me dynamical content. What should i do for fix that? Thanks

```
let puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async() => {
const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
let page = await browser.newPage();
const url = 'https://abcdsite.com/';
let arrayNames = ['first','second','third','abcd'];
for(let i=0;i<await arrayNames.length;){
    let nameUrl = await arrayNames[i];
    if (i<4){
      let temp1;
      console.log(`begin for ${nameUrl}`);
      await page.goto(`${url}${nameUrl}`, { waitUntil: 'load' })
          .then(()=>{
            return new Promise(res=>{
              //wait content dynamic load
              setTimeout(()=>{
                temp1 = page.evaluate(() => {
                  return new Promise(resolve => { // <-- return the data to node.js from browser
                    let name = document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
                    let email = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-views-contacts h-card vcard')[0]
                        .children[2].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;
                    resolve(email);
                  });
                });
                res(temp1);
              },7000);

            })
      })
          .then((res)=>{
            i++;
            console.log(`https://abcdsite.com/${nameUrl}`,temp1);
          });
    }
    else{
      break
    }
  }
})();
```

Comment: Are you trying to do this in parallel or series??

Comment: @Saeeed it first i have tried parallel way, but i had all of results like pending-promises((

Answer (score 2):

I think this helps you.

1) make an async function to request and parse your data

2) create an array of parallel tasks.

```
let puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

async function makeRequest(page, url, nameUrl) {
  await page.goto(`${url}${nameUrl}`, { waitUntil: 'load' });

  setTimeout(() => {
    const userEmail = await page.evaluate(() => {
      let name = document.querySelector('h1').innerHTML;
      let email = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-views-contacts h-card vcard')[0]
        .children[2].children[0].children[0].innerHTML;

      return email;
    });

    return Promise.resolve(userEmail);
  }, 7000);
}

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  let page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = 'https://abcdsite.com/';
  let arrayNames = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'abcd'];

  let tasks = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
    tasks.push(makeRequest(page, url, arrayNames[i]));
  }

  Promise.all(tasks)
    .then((res) => {
      for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
        console.log(`https://abcdsite.com/${arrayNames[i]}`, res[i]);
      }
    });

})();
```

---

**Series solution**

For more information read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37576685/using-async-await-with-a-foreach-loop).

```
for (let i = 0; i < arrayNames.length; i++) {
  let temp = await makeRequest(page, url, arrayNames[i]);
  console.log(`https://abcdsite.com/${arrayNames[i]}`, temp);
}
```

Comment: it writes me ```Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 Symbol(Events.FrameManager.FrameDetached) listeners added to [FrameManager]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit```

Comment: How many pages you trying to fetch? Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected) question and its answers. @diesel94

Comment: i try to load 1600 pages . In your article they told about slimerJS. I have tried to add ```require('events').EventEmitter.prototype._maxListeners = 1700;``` but not success(

Comment: 1600 pages!! That's a lot. You should use another approach. Is it important to get them as fast as possible?? You can do it series. Or you can fetch N pages in each task! @diesel94

Comment: no, i can wait for an hour if needed) i realize that it is hard to do this fast, so i want to do that in any way

Comment: hey, i have tried to do that for 10 pieces and it works **but** it is ```undefined``` for ```res[i]``` in the console

Comment: There was a missing `await` in **makeRequest** function. copy it again. @diesel94

Comment: it worked without async, but ```res[i]``` the same for every item and = last email of the list which consoled. with async it ```...``` for every item it is mean that emails had not been loaded on sites dynamically when we got them

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212418/discussion-between-saeed-and-diesel94).

Answer (score 1):

puppeteer's `page.goto` function has multiple parameters you can use to ensure that the page is fully loaded. See the documentation [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagegotourl-options).
In addition, you can use the `page.waitFor` method to wait for a few seconds. See documentation [here](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagewaitforselectororfunctionortimeout-options-args).

Here you have a simple example that I think may work for you:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

const url = 'https://stackoverflow.com/'
const arrayNames = ['tags', 'users', 'jobs', 'questions'];

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch()
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  const data = {}
  for (const nameUrl of arrayNames) {
    const fullUrl = `${url}${nameUrl}`
    console.log(`begin for ${fullUrl}`)
    await page.goto(fullUrl, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' }) // check networkidle0 parameter and others here: https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.1.1&show=api-pagegotourl-options
    await page.waitFor(2000) // wait 2 seconds to allow a full login. Optional
    const pageData = await page.evaluate(() => {
      const name = document.querySelector('h1').innerText
      const pageTitle = document.querySelector('title').innerText
      // get whatever data you need to get from the page.
      return { name: name, title: pageTitle }
    })
    console.log('\t Data from page: ', pageData)
    data[fullUrl] = pageData
  }
  console.log(data)
})()
```

This does not run all sites in parallel, but you can then play around with the example.
Instead of 'awaiting' the `await page.evaluate` part, you could get all the promises in an array and then use `await Promise.all([listOfPromises])`

Comment: i have tried this way, but it doesn't give aswers for all data, only for data from sites (which  arrived in time) , for another sites it is not dynamic data arrived in time and i get only stub '...' when data has not loaded on site yet. i get smth like that  


```abcdsite.com/spurit ⋯

abcdsite.com/senticode ⋯

abcdsite.com/instinctools ⋯

abcdsite.com/codemaster info@codemaster.by

abcdsite.com/dewpoint ⋯

abcdsite.com/01d ⋯

abcdsite.com/12devs ⋯

abcdsite.com/onepoint ⋯
```

Comment: ```tempPage.waitFor(7000);``` not work for me at all (

Comment: i have checked it with {headless: false}

Comment: Hi @diesel94, I am not sure I understood your issue. Maybe you can provide a URL example where this can be reproduced.
Maybe, the javascript you are running inside the page.evaluate function, isn't working on all pages. The provided example should work on any valid page.

Comment: It works at all pages, but always for different) somitimes for 20%, sometomes for 50, 90%. Example : dev.by/onepoint; dev.by/spurit etc.

Comment: Sorry, still not sure what is happening in your case. 
If I use the code above, and replace the URLs with the ones you provided, it still works for me.
`const url = 'https://dev.by/';`
`const arrayNames = ['news', 'spurit', 'onepoint', 'questions'];`
This is what I get:
`{'https://dev.by/news':{name: 'Новости', title: 'Новости | dev.by' },'https://dev.by/spurit':{name: 'dev.by', title: '\n ИТ в Беларуси | dev.by\n' },'https://dev.by/onepoint':{name: 'dev.by', title: '\n ИТ в Беларуси | dev.by\n' },'https://dev.by/questions':{name: 'dev.by', title: '\n ИТ в Беларуси | dev.by\n' }
}`

Comment: You have parsed static content. Look at email, and company name throw ‘’’email’’’ variable, at my code at the topic. It is dynamically content, which will be like “...” with your way.

Comment: Hi. Actually, I didn't test the email part because the urls you provided are returning a 404 not found page. The only one that works is https://dev.by/news and the selector `document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-views-contacts h-card vcard')[0]` doesn't return anything. 
Maybe you are testing with other pages... ?

Comment: i am sorry ! The right way is with prefix “companies” like ‘’’https://companies.dev.by/spurit’’’. Check it now please

Comment: Hi again. I tryied the code with this URLS: `const url = 'https://companies.dev.by/'
const arrayNames = ['spurit', 'senticode', 'instinctools', 'codemaster', 'dewpoint', '01d', '12devs', 'onepoint'];` and it works just fine. I don't know if you have modified the code, but for me it works just fine as it is. I also added the email `const email = document.getElementsByClassName('sidebar-views-contacts h-card vcard')[0].children[2].children[0].children[0].innerText; return { name: name, title: pageTitle, email: email }`

Comment: Hmm, the difference in your and my code is in cycle “for”. I use ‘’’for ( , , )’’’ loop. I will check exactly your code above tomorrow

Comment: Man!! your method is pefect! I changed ```for(let i =0 ...``` loop to ```for(const url of array)``` and all works pefect. I dont know what the difference between that methods but Thank you very much

Comment: oh, i have tried it for 10 items and it is works fine, but when i try it for 20+ items it again does not have time to capture data(

Comment: i copy/paste your code and in the console i get ```begin for spurit
         Data from page:  { name: '"SpurIT"', email: 'contact@spur-i-t.com' }
begin for senticode
         Data from page:  { name: '"Сэнтикод"', email: '⋯' }
begin for instinctools
         Data from page:  { name: '*instinctools', email: '⋯' }
begin for codemaster
         Data from page:  { name: '//CODEMASTER', email: 'info@codemaster.by' }
begin for dewpoint
         Data from page:  { name: '°dewpoint ', email: '⋯' }
begin for 01d
         Data from page:  { name: '01D', email: '⋯' }
```