# Error while creating React app in VS code

Tags: node.js, reactjs

When I try to create a React app using `npx create-react-app file2`, I am getting an error like this:

> (node:19956) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 close listeners added to [TLSSocket]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit.

How can I resolve it?

I have tried to check it in chatgpt, but cannot find the exact response. I am expecting the error to be modified.

Comment: you can check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768444/possible-eventemitter-memory-leak-detected) i hope it helps.