# Has no method 'setMaxListeners' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, request

According to [this question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners) I need to call `request.setMaxListeners(0)` to solve the problem described.

When I try to do:

```
var request = require('request');
request.setMaxListeners(0);
```

I get the following error message:

```
request.setMaxListeners(0);
        ^ TypeError: Object function request(uri, options, callback) {   if (typeof uri === 'undefined') throw new Error('undefined is not a valid uri or options object.')   if ((typeof options === 'function') && !callback) callback = options   if (options && typeof options === 'object') {
    options.uri = uri   } else if (typeof uri === 'string') {
    options = {uri:uri}   } else {
    options = uri   }

  options = copy(options)

  if (callback) options.callback = callback   var r = new Request(options)   return r } has no method 'setMaxListeners'
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/vagrant/twitter/test.js:3:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:901:3
```

How do I correctly adjust the default value for `setMaxListeners` when using the request-module?

**node --version: 0.10.4**
**request module version: 2.16.6**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### EDIT

After a bit disscussion i think you are trying to do something like this, after "setMaxListeners"

```
var request = require('request');

// this will fail
request.setMaxListeners(0);

request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  // do something ...
})
```

### Step by step

```
var request = require('request');
```

The request module is required. This module exports [the function request](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/index.js#L1209).

This function **does not** inherit from the [EventEmitter](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_class_events_eventemitter)
 - an internal node "class" - so it does not have the ["setMaxListeners method"](http://nodejs.org/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n).

With this in mind, the following line will fail

```
request.setMaxListeners(0);
```

You need a [Request object](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/index.js#L100), that [inherits from the EventEmitter](https://github.com/mikeal/request/blob/master/index.js#L122) and has the desired method.

To get one, simply call the request function. On the value returned by this function, you can call "setMaxListeners".

```
var request_object = request('http://www.google.com')
request_object.setMaxListeners(0)
```

Better if we chain the calls

```
request('http://www.google.com').setMaxListeners(0)
```

## Warning

I **do not recomend at all** removing the max listeners limit. Some kind of infinite loop may be the problem - maybe a listener being bound on each "request" event - to throw a "too much listeners bound" error. **This error is an effective method to detect memory leaks, so i recommend raising a bit the "maxListeners" limit rather than setting it to "unlimited"**.

To do this, pass a int != 0. As a note, the default value is 10.

```
request(
  //
  // request stuff goes here
  //
).setMaxListeners(20)
```

## The Answer

```
var request = require('request');

request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  //
  // do something ...
  //
}).setMaxListeners(20)
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for your answer. I am using the `request` module (`npm install request`).

Comment: is [this one](https://github.com/mikeal/request) the module you are ussing? If so, i will recomend an eye on its readme. If you post the full snipnet of code with what you are trying to do, i could help you more

Comment: Oh wow. Good answer. Thanks a lot. I am going to try this ASAP. I guess I went to far in cutting the code down to the minimum neccessary to reproduce the problem.