# Meteor JS event emitter error when loading cordova plugins

Tags: javascript, cordova, meteor

Hi guys I have gone through a lot of sources here:

[node.js - request - How to "emitter.setMaxListeners()"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners)

http://www.jongleberry.com/understanding-possible-eventemitter-leaks.html

and a lot more sources regarding "**eventemitter**".

All of the suggestions about adding setMaxListeners on both client/server did not work due to the error occurs when building the mobile app on the part where it downloads the cordova plugins.

Does anybody encounter this issue? Any solution or suggestions? Please advice. Thank you.

Comment: From you question it is difficult to tell what is the problem. Some suggestions: What is the error? What is your setup? Did it build before? If so, what did you change? Is there relevant code that you can submit? Can you isolate and reproduce it?

Comment: I found the solution, I am not sure why but I fixed it by just deleting the folder where the APK is being built and then do meteor reset . . I ran the build again and no more error :)