# Real-time data acquisition from serial port with node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, real-time

I am working on a project that requires real-time data acquisition from the serial port. Data flow is really fast and it's basically a list of points measured in real time. I am working with [serialport](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serialport) in order to handle the communication part, [socket.io](https://www.npmjs.com/package/socket.io) to communicate with the client (A web page that contains a chart where points should be plotted). When I send 1 point per second, it works fine but when the data flow is fast (like 1 point/10ms) node.js shows this error:

> MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak
>   detected. 11 data listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to
>   increase limit

My question is:Is there a solution to handle such a fast flow in real-time? My first thoughts where about using a producer consumer algorithm and a queue to collect data from serial port. What I would like to know if there is more optimized solutions.

The scenario is like this:

Node:js: GET_VALUE
Microcontroller: 1234
Node:js: GET_VALUE
Microcontroller: 5678

My code:

```
function readFromUART() {
        chosenPort.write(cmdGetValue, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            return console.log('Error on write: ', err.message);
        }
        });
            console.log('NODE: GATHER DATA');
        parser.on('data', function(data){
            console.log(data);
```

This function is called every X ms

```
setInterval(readFromUART, 1000);
```

Comment: Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution. It's better to use [eventemitter3](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter3) rather than [eventemmiter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/eventemitter). It has high performance in real-time applications.

> var EventEmitter = require('eventemitter3');
>
> var eventEmitter = new EventEmitter();