# How to properly insert the Geonames 1.5Gib file into Postgresql using Node?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, geonames

I've downloaded Geonames database dump and I'm trying to put everything in a postgresql table but I keep running into multiple errors no matter what I try.

Last modification I made I got the following:

```
Error: Connection terminated by user
    at Client.end (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:402:36)
    at Pool._remove (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:135:12)
    at Timeout.setTimeout (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg-pool/index.js:38:12)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
Line added  6052 0.05135667935111022%
(node:31819) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: This socket is closed
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:729:18)
    at Socket._write (net.js:783:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:397:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:383:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:290:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:707:40)
    at Connection.end (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg/lib/connection.js:318:22)
    at global.Promise (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:410:23)
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Client.end (/media/DarkHawk/srv/Databases/PremadeDB/Geonames/node_modules/pg/lib/client.js:409:12)
(node:31819) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:31819) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
(node:31819) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 end listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit
```

My code is:

```
var pg = require("pg");
var fs = require('fs');

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: 'smurf',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'smurf',
  port: 5432,
})

var filename = 'allCountries.txt';

var fs = require('fs'),
  es = require('event-stream');

var lineNr = 0;
var max = 11784251; // Number of line, dirty, to get % of lines inserted

// Connect to Postgresql
pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) throw err

  // Stream file line by line
  var s = fs.createReadStream(filename)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.mapSync(function(e) {

        // pause the readstream
        s.pause();

        lineNr += 1;

        // Each line need to be properly formated
        e = e.split("\t"); //TAB split

        // The following fields need formating
        e[0] = parseInt(e[0]);
        e[4] = parseFloat(e[4]);
        e[5] = parseFloat(e[5]);
        e[14] = parseInt(e[14]);

        e[15] = e[15] == '' ? 0 : e[15];

        e[16] = parseInt(e[16]);

        // Insert into db
        pool.query('INSERT INTO geonames.rawdata (geonameid, name, asciiname, alternatenames, latitude, longitude, fclass, fcode, country, cc2, admin1, admin2, admin3, admin4, population, elevation, gtopo30, timezone, moddate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19);', e, function(err, result) {
          if (err) {
            console.log(err);

          }
          done(); // Release this connection to the pool
          console.log("Line added ", lineNr, (lineNr / max * 100) + "%") // Monitor progress
          s.resume(); // Go to next line

        });

      })
      .on('error', function(err) {
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
      })
      .on('end', function() {
        console.log('Read entire file.')
      })
    );
}) // END pool.connect
```

I tried with ReadFile, ReadFileSync, readline extension. Moving or ommiting the `done()` function or just moving it around.

I usually use php to insert massive files so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

The **MaxListenersExceededWarning** error makes no sense to me because it seems like I close everything that I open. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried changing the default max listeners? I think there is a limit but I have never had an issue with this. [Ref](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/events.html#events_eventemitter_defaultmaxlisteners)

Comment: I don't understand why the max listeners would be reached as I close everything. I'm confused. Changing max listener with `require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 40;` (from this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners) doesn't get me farther in the process (~6500 lines)

Comment: This is because you're flooding your pg database with entries using `mapSync`. What it does, it creates inserts, but doesn't wait unitl those are completed.

Try using `es.map` instead and use a callback after the data is inserted. You can also use my [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet) and use pg with es6 async/await code - it should be easier. [This sample](https://github.com/signicode/scramjet/blob/master/samples/so-examples/csv-to-stored-procedure.js) shows a similar caase.

Comment: @MichałKapracki I forgot to let you know that you were right, obviously :) Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: Hmm... I can make this to an answer...

Comment: Sure go ahead @MichałKapracki :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - when you work on asynchronous code you need to use `map` instead of `mapSync` operation and call the callback after the item has been inserted.

If you use this, the call to `pause` and `resume` is not needed anymore (this is done by `event-stream`), you just need to resume the last stream you create. Then there's the question when `done` should be called - that is: after all operations are completed.

Your code should look like this:

```
var pg = require("pg");
var fs = require('fs');

const pool = new pg.Pool({
  user: 'smurf',
  host: 'localhost',
  database: 'mydb',
  password: 'smurf',
  port: 5432,
})

var filename = 'allCountries.txt';

var fs = require('fs'),
    es = require('event-stream');

var lineNr = 0;
var max = 11784251; // Number of line, dirty, to get % of lines inserted

// Connect to Postgresql
pool.connect((err, client, done) => {
  if (err) throw err

  // Stream file line by line
  var s = fs.createReadStream(filename)
    .pipe(es.split())
    .pipe(es.map(function(e, cb) {

        lineNr += 1;

        // Each line need to be properly formated
        e = e.split("\t"); //TAB split

        // The following fields need formating
        e[0] = parseInt(e[0]);
        e[4] = parseFloat(e[4]);
        e[5] = parseFloat(e[5]);
        e[14] = parseInt(e[14]);

        e[15] = e[15] == '' ? 0 : e[15];

        e[16] = parseInt(e[16]);

        // Insert into db
        pool.query('INSERT INTO geonames.rawdata (geonameid, name, asciiname, alternatenames, latitude, longitude, fclass, fcode, country, cc2, admin1, admin2, admin3, admin4, population, elevation, gtopo30, timezone, moddate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19);', e, function(err, result) {
            cb(err, result); // call the callback
            console.log("Line added ", lineNr, (lineNr / max * 100) + "%") // Monitor progress
        });

    })
    .resume()
    .on('error', function(err) {
        done();
        console.log('Error while reading file.', err);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
        done();
        console.log('Read entire file.')
    })
    );
}) // END pool.connect
```

The above version of the code will not make use of the pool you're creating - it will operate on one item at once.

If you're using a fairly recent node (8.4+) you can use a framework of my own [`scramjet`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/scramjet/) which would allow to write an even simpler code with the use of ES6 async functions:

```
const {Pool} = require("pg");
const {StringStream} = require("scramjet");
const fs = require("fs");

const pool = new Pool(options);
const max = 11784251;
const INSERT_ENTRY = 'INSERT INTO geonames.rawdata (geonameid, name, asciiname, alternatenames, latitude, longitude, fclass, fcode, country, cc2, admin1, admin2, admin3, admin4, population, elevation, gtopo30, timezone, moddate) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6, $7, $8, $9, $10, $11, $12, $13, $14, $15, $16, $17, $18, $19);';

StringStream
    .from(fs.createReadStream(filename))
    .lines()
    .parse(line => {
        // Each line need to be properly formated
        const entry = line.split("\t"); //TAB split

        // The following fields need formating
        entry[0] = parseInt(entry[0]);
        entry[4] = parseFloat(entry[4]);
        entry[5] = parseFloat(entry[5]);
        entry[14] = parseInt(entry[14]);
        entry[15] = entry[15] == '' ? 0 : entry[15];
        entry[16] = parseInt(entry[16]);

        return entry;
    })
    .setOptions({maxParallel: 32})
    .each(entry => {
        const client = await pool.connect();
        try {
            await client.query(INSERT_ENTRY, entry)
        } catch(err) {
            console.log('Error while adding line...', err);
            // some more logic could be here?
        } finally {
            client.release();
        }
    })
    .each(() => !(lineNr++ % 1000) && console.log("Line added ", lineNr, (lineNr / max * 100) + "%"))
    .run()
    .then(
        () => console.log('Read entire file.'), 
        e => console.log('Error while handling file.', err)
    );
```

The code above will attempt to run 32 parallel inserts using the pool (requesting a client on every entry - the [`pg pool.query`](https://node-postgres.com/api/pool#pool-query-gt-promise-pg-result-) method will reuse and add clients to it's set limit. This doesn't mean necessarily it'll be 32 times quicker - as there are some external limiting factors, but you should see a drastic increase in speed.