# MaxListenersExceededWarnin Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberAdd listeners added to [Client]

Tags: javascript, discord.js, dom-events, jimp

I'm trying to make a code using jimp in which, when a member enters the discord server, they sends a welcome picture, like their nickname and avatar. In the channel set by the ID, they sends the image, but they sends 11 images, and in the console they sends 11 messages saying:

> "Imagem enviada para o discord".

However, this error came and I don't know how to fix it. The entire error:

> "MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 guildMemberAdd listeners added to [Client]. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit"

Here is my code:

```js
client.on("guildMemberAdd", async member => {
  
  let canal = client.channels.cache.get("684821700038098967")
  let fonte = await jimp.loadFont(jimp.FONT_SANS_32_WHITE)
  let mask = await jimp.read('mascara.png')
  let fundo = await jimp.read('fundo2.png')


  jimp.read(member.user.defaultAvatarURL).then(avatar => {
      avatar.resize(130, 130)
      mask.resize(130, 130)
      avatar.mask(mask)
      fundo.print(fonte, 170, 175, member.user.username)
      fundo.composite(avatar,30, 70).write('beta.png')
      canal.send(``, { files: ["beta.png"]})

      console.log('Imagem enviada para o Discord')
     })
    .catch(err =>  {
  console.log('Error avatar')
  })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I already resolved.
I was putting this event inside an event

Comment: please follow[How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in [the node eventEmitter documentation](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/events.html#events_emitter_setmaxlisteners_n)

In short, its: process.setMaxListeners(0);

Also see: [node.js - request - How to “emitter.setMaxListeners()”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313628/node-js-request-how-to-emitter-setmaxlisteners)